# Multilevel Hook Order

Tags: 7, hooks

I have two custom modules well just call them one and two for now, both have a hook onto `hook_node_insert()`. However, module two also has a hook into module one that is initiated by it's hook to `node_insert()`. So here is what the code would look like:

```
//one.module
one_node_insert($node) {
    //some code here
    module_invoke_all('one_complete', $node);
}

//two.module
two_node_insert($node) {
    //some code here
}
two_one_complete($node) {
    //some different code here
}
```

What order do the hooks get called if the weight for module two is 0 and the weight for module one is -1? Logically I would think the order would be:

`one_node_insert->two_one_complete-> two_node_insert`

But from just a little bit of testing it seems to be

`one_node_insert->two_node_insert->two_one_complete`

So my question is does drupal some how run hooks in levels? In other words does it run all functions directly hooked to node_insert before it continues down the line of other hooks?

Comment: No, `module_invoke_all()` runs to its full conclusion every time it's called, there's no waiting until an earlier invocation of the same has completed. It's a totally linear process, if that makes sense. Maybe you could outline your debugging methods? I think it's more likely those are giving false results. Logically speaking, if the _one_ module's `hook_node_insert()` implementation is running first, then the order should be exactly what you expect. Is it possible `two_node_insert` is actually firing first and skewing your results?

Comment: If that is the case then the weight on the module isn't working correctly. I'll add some debuging code to see if that is the case though. Just wondering is the module weight stored somewhere in cache possibly?